# Como usar o filter() para selecionar apenas uma parte da string?

Tags: r

Quero filtrar por um termo que nem sempre aparece sozinho e o número de combinações é enorme. A minha variável **LINHAII** tem vários códigos e eu quero filtrar as ocorrências que contém **E119**. Porém, a filtragem retorna somente as ocorrências únicas, quando ela está sozinha.

```r
library(tidyverse)

dados <- filter(df_datasus, LINHAII %in% '*E119')
```

Nos casos onde aparece ***E119*I10X**, por exemplo, não há retorno dessa linha.

Como filtrar apenas por um trecho de interesse?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O `%in%`serve apenas para procurar elemento. Ele vai procurar elementos que sejam exatamente iguais a algum elemento de um vetor. No seu caso ele realmente só procura strings exatamente iguais `'*E119'`.

Se você quer realizar uma busca dentro de strings eu recomendo usar o `str_detect` do pacote `stringr`, que tem boa documentação e já faz parte do `tidyverse`,

```
dados <- filter(df_datasus, str_detect(LINHAII,'E119'))
```

Eles vai selecionar qualquer linha em que a variável `LINHAII` contenha o termo E119.
Se você quiser valores que tenha E119 em alguma posição específica ou com algum valor antes/depois é só manipular a expressão regular, que é a segunda parte de `str_detect`.

Answer (score 5):

Uma opção é o `grepl`, que devolve `TRUE/FALSE` caso encontre ou não uma expressão regular. O asterisco deve ser precedido de `\\` porque é um metacarater.

```
filter(df_datasus, grepl('\\*E119', LINHAII))
```